# xamarin android development debugging error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I see this error while building xamarin.android:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Exception while loading assemblies: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? 
File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll' at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() App3.Droid?
```

Comment: You should explain what were you trying to do when this happened, and paste a bit of code. 

From what I can read here, it looks like you're missing Android.Support.v7 in your solution's components. Click on Components, then add component, and search for Android.Support.v7.

Comment: I am building this basic code to diplay "welcome to xamarin forms"

namespace App3
{
 public class App : Application
 {
  public App ()
  {
   // The root page of your application
   MainPage = new ContentPage {
    Content = new StackLayout {
     VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
     Children = {
      new Label {
       HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
       Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
      }
     }
    }
   };
  }

  protected override void OnStart ()
  {
   // Handle when your app starts
  }

  protected override void OnSleep ()

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if the version of Android.Support is either missing or unusable. This can normally be resolved by clearing out the packages and downloading them again.

To do this, please follow the steps below:

1. Remove all packages from Android App (including Forms)
2. Add Xamarin.Forms from NuGet

The act of adding Xamarin.Forms from NuGet will retrieve the correct versions of the various Android support libraries, including those that are throwing the error and/or missing.

Please let me know if this resolves the issue.
 
Thanks!

Comment: I have tried this, and it pulled same packages and still getting same error. The only difference is, mine missing assembly is : Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat